# ios AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer convert between camera and screen coordinates

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, avcapturesession

I use AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer to show preview video layer, sample images from that preview and do some processing on it.
The processing recognises some points on the image and returns them. i want to show those points on the preview layer in (almost) real time.

I have some trouble converting those points, specially when switching between orientations.

This is how i install the preview layer:

```
self.previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:self.captureSession];
self.previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
```

This is how i get image from the layer:

```
- (void)processPixelBuffer: (CVImageBufferRef)pixelBuffer {

  CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress( pixelBuffer, 0 );



  CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer,0);
  uint8_t *baseAddress = (uint8_t *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer);
  size_t bbytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer);
  size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer);
  size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer);
  CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
  CGContextRef myContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8, bbytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);   

  self.cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(myContext);
  CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress( pixelBuffer, 0 );

  //image processing ...
}
```

Now what i get is the points in this image coordinates system.
What i need is a method to convert it to screen coordinates to present it on the screen

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so after re-reading the AVCapturePreviewLayer API, here is a pretty strait-forward and simple solution:

```
CGFloat imWidth = CGImageGetWidth(self.cgImage);
CGFloat imHeight = CGImageGetHeight(self.cgImage);

CGPoint point = /* point in image coordinates*/;
point.x = point.x/imWidth;
point.y = point.y/imHeight;
CGPoint screenPoint = [self.previewLayer pointForCaptureDevicePointOfInterest:point];
```

Tried this method at first but got strange result because i forgot to normalize the coordinates to values between 0.0 and 1.0 as required this function documentation.

BTW, the other way around is also possible with the method

```
captureDevicePointOfInterestForPoint:
```